# How to achieve dynamic data structure for a dynamic select query in XML Data Template?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a lexical parameter in the data query part which fetches dynamic select query.Now I want to know how to display the elements of select query or how to acheive dynamic data structure in XML.

```
<dataQuery> 
<sqlStatement name="Q_DATA">
<![CDATA[
&x_sql]]>
</sqlStatement>
</dataQuery>

<dataStructure> 
<group name="G_DATA" source="Q_DATA">
-----------------------------------
</dataStructure>
```

Comment: show us what you tried.

Comment: @Exhausted-I dont have any idea how to approach this problem.Please help me.